# Getting Started on HTML5 for Web Interactive Films

Tags: html, video, interactive

Do you have any links to quick tutorials to add interactivity to video using HTML 5 to replace Flash?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do, and also detail what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

How to create a streaming in HTML5? There are many way for do it. You can use tags `<video>`, `<source>` and `<track>` and use JavaScript + node.js too.
Like hosting I can reccomend you a VPS or any hosting with many memory (Don't use Altervista or hosting like it). If you would only do a streaming easy and don't complex, you can use any project free, like [this](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/streaming-audio-and-video-with-html-5/)

[or these](http://easyhtml5video.com/help/streaming-html5-video-8.html)